# where did the extra solution go?

Tags: systems-of-equations, analytic-geometry

The question is:
Find all real values k such that the circle $x^2+y^2=9$ and parabola $y=x^2+k$ have no points of intersection.

It is clear that when $k > 3$, no points of intersection exist. There is also another range when $k$ is negative, so when you substitute:

$y-k = x^2$

$y-k+y^2 = 9$

$y^2 + y - (k+9) = 0$

The discriminant must be negative so

$1 + 4(k+9) < 0$

$k < -37/4$

However, the original range $k > 3$ disappeared. Does anyone know what I did wrong?

Comment: Your substitution is wrong. You should be solving for $x$, this means you need to have $x = \sqrt{y - k}$. Then plug this $x$ into $x^{2}$.

Comment: $-37/4$ is a correct bound, but you should look at the polynomial $x^2+(x^2+k)^2=9$. This polynomial only has real roots for $k\notin[-\frac{37}{4},3]$.